# What is the correct choice Computer (make a computer-do computer)?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, expressions

If a company manufactures new computers, which is the correct way to describe this process; 'do computers' or 'make computers'?  I think it is 'make computers', because 'do' refers to a physical action while make refers to a new creation of something, but I'm not sure which is correct.

Comment: This question is more suited to English Language Learners. What is the sentence in which you want to use the expression? If you can't use _manufacture, make_ is certainly far better than _do_, which would sound very informal and not very idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you are asking this question because عـَمـَل means both make and do.

Here is the definition of **make** from the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make): "to produce something, often using a particular substance or material". You are right: in writing or in formal conversation, **make** is the best verb to describe what a manufacturer does.

> This company makes computers

Note that **do** has another meaning, apart from carrying out an action. According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/do), it can also mean "to make, produce, or create something". I would regard this usage as quite informal. Here is an example:

> This café does the best carrot cake in town.

So, in informal conversation, you could say

> This company does computers

Comment: It's true that we can use "do" informally as you suggest but it should be noted that the cafe does not have to be baking the cakes nor does the computer company have to be manufacturing the computers; they could both be buying the product from a supplier. In most cases the customers would not care. If we say "makes", however, we would know that the company was producing the product. Also I have studied three other languages to a very basic level and in all of those "make" and "do" are translated into the same word. I believe that English is unusual in having two words.